# Angular 15 upgrade breaks path parameter handling

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular15

We are in the process of upgrading from Angular v13 to v17. The upgrade to v14 was a breeze compared to the upgrade to v15. Aside from the complete Material UI overhaul we experience also a breaking change regarding the use of path parameters from our routes.

We have the following (subset of) routes:

```
public static readonly ACCOUNT_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'account/:id',
    pathMatch: 'prefix',
    children: [
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'summary' },
      { path: 'summary', component: AccountSummaryComponent },
      { path: 'cost', component: AccountCostComponent }
    ],
  },
];
```

To handle the account id we have `AccountService` that has an observable for the account id:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AccountService implements OnDestroy {

  // Account ID
  private accountIdSubscription: Subscription;
  public readonly accountId$: Observable<number> = RouterUtil.pathParam$(
    this.router,
    (url: UrlSegment[]) => {
      if (url[0].path !== 'account') return null;
      return parseInt(url[1].path);
    }
  );

  // Account
  /**
   * The investment account data for the current account id. The observable is
   * cleared on logout and updated when the account id changes.
   */
  public readonly account$: Observable<AccountResp> = this.accountId$.pipe(
    switchMap((id: number) => (id ? this.apiService.getAccount(id) : of(null)))
  );

  constructor(
    private readonly router: Router,
    private readonly apiService: ApiService,
  ) {
    this.accountIdSubscription = this.accountId$.subscribe();
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.accountIdSubscription?.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

The `RouterUtil` utility class is implemented as:

```
export class RouterUtil {
  /**
   * Observable for current URL in application as an array of UrlSegments
   */
  public static currentURL$(router: Router): Observable<UrlSegment[]> {
    return router.events.pipe(
      // Log events
      tap((e: Event) => console.log(e)),
      // Filter NavigationEnd
      filter((e: Event): e is NavigationEnd => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
      // Parse URL
      map((e: NavigationEnd) => {
        const tree: UrlTree = router.parseUrl(e.url);
        const g: UrlSegmentGroup = tree.root.children[PRIMARY_OUTLET];
        return g ? g.segments : null;
      })
    );
  }

  /**
   * Observable for parameter of current URL.
   */
  public static pathParam$<T>(router: Router, getParam: (url: UrlSegment[]) => T): Observable<T> {
    return RouterUtil.currentURL$(router).pipe(
      filterNull,
      map((url: UrlSegment[]) => getParam(url)),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    );
  }
}
```

In the `AccountSummaryComponent` we have the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-account-summary',
  templateUrl: './account-summary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account-summary.component.scss'],
})
export class AccountSummaryComponent {
  public readonly account$: Observable<AccountResp> = this.accountService.account$;

  constructor(private readonly accountService: AccountService) {}
}
```

In the template we use:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="account$ | async as account">
  ....
</ng-container>
```

When running this with Angular v14 the page would load correctly when being router there through the app itself. But also when we refresh the browser window (tried with Edge, Chrome, Firefox) the data loads correctly. In the console we see many router events being logged.

After the upgrade to Angular v15 the page will still load correct when being routed through the app but it will fail when I refresh the browser window. I only see a `Scroll` router event, no other events.

However, when I switch to the `cost` route (tabbed navigation) the `AccountCostComponent` will show the proper data and all relevant router events are logged. Reloading this page again fails with only the `Scroll` router event.

I've looked at the v15 upgrade page but couldn't find anything other than `getCurrentNavigation()` that could be related to what I'm seeing.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Other things I've observed:

- The `AccountService` constructor is executed. Verified by including a log message in the constructor.
- The component constructors are all executed. Again, verified by including some logging.